# 403 Forbidden error when accessing site (Joomla)

Tags: joomla

When I restored my website backup and tried to enter my web page, it says:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /public_html on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What it means?

It means that your web server doesn't have the permissions to read the folder in which you have your `Joomla` installed.

### If you have access to the folder

If you can access to your server with a client FTP like `FileZilla` you should be able to right-click on the folder and then edit `File Permission` and set the `Numeric value:` to `775`, which should allow the webserver to read and write.

Remember to check the checkbox of `Recurse into subdirectories`.

### If you don't feel secure

In case nothing of the above make sense just contact your hosting provider and ask them to change the `permissions` of your folder.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Borraccia the permission check box for world to read and execute wasn't checked :)

Answer (score 0):

but for me it didn't work. so I googled and found following solution. 
just added in .htacess file at the bottom along with "why reason" so if this will work fine and i will remove if not..

```
########## Attempt to solve 'Global Configuration' save issue, FTP layer issue, Media Upload issue
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
########## End - Attempt to solve 'Global Configuration' save issue, FTP layer issue, Media Upload issue
```

And it worked smoothly. :)

so the rewards goes to.. somebody named **fived** on Joomla community. 
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=265427#p1216787